# How to Copy or Clone a viewport?

Tags: vb.net, viewport, autocad, autocad-plugin

What is the correct way of copying an existing viewport, What I am actually doing is that to clone a layout by copying what is inside it, everything works smoothly except for the viewports.
I tried to use the clone method, but it didn't work, I also tried to use the copyfrom method but also to no avail.
In both cases the copied viewport is a dumb black rectangle

```
Dim exkeyvport As Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.Viewport = DirectCast(acTrans.GetObject(objId, OpenMode.ForRead), Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.Viewport)
Dim keyvport As New Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.Viewport

keyvport.CopyFrom(exkeyvport)
keyvport.UpdateDisplay()
NewblkTableRec.AppendEntity(keyvport)
acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(keyvport, True)
```

The only way that partially worked for me was to create a viewport and copy its attributes one by one, but this is exhaustive and not reliable, so could anyone tell us of the proper way to copy a viewport?

Comment: Viewport.deepClone()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for others who are interested on the details on how to perform the deepclone here is the code:
objid refers to the viewport object id

```
 If (objId.ObjectClass.DxfName.ToUpper = "VIEWPORT") Then
                    Dim id As ObjectId = newLayout.BlockTableRecordId
                    Dim idcol As New ObjectIdCollection
                    idcol.Add(objId)
                    Dim idmap As New IdMapping
                    acCurdb.DeepCloneObjects(idcol, acCurdb.CurrentSpaceId, idmap, False)
  End if
```